# Is there any way to transfer for the execute file form linux to window?

Tags: linux

I got a souce code in linux system. That's why my executeable file can be execute in linux.

Since that I can makefile in linux. But I'd like to make an executeable file in Window system  the same.

But I didn't got any source code in Window system. Can I use any software to transfer my

execute file like "aaa"  to  "aaa.exe" in Window system and can be executed.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, you could compile it on windows so the target exe would be for Windows system. Linux and Windows use different executable formats. Linux uses ELF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

If it is source code that can be compiled under Windows and does not use Unix specific libraries, you are home.

Comment: O.K. I think that may be the conclusion is that I had to do some porting work!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons people are looking at platforms like [java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), [python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) and other virtual machine runtime platforms. Your code and executable should be able to run on multiple platforms. Those operating systems on which the platforms have been ported.

Another options would be to install a virtual machine system like [virtual box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to install linux under your windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

Give some more details. For instance what language are you using?  Does your source require any files that would not be present on a Windows system? What compilers are you using in your Linux and Windows environments? Even with out these details the short answer to your question is no, there is no software that will just magically make a program coded *specifically* for Linux work in Windows. You will need to do some porting work.

Comment: She wants to do it without even recompiling, which will definitely not work (unless the executable is actually an interpreted script, but then why would she be using a Makefile?)

Comment: I an using gcc compile language in linux Ubuntu, My souce does not require any other file present on Window XP system.

Comment: @Angela [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) is a compiler, not a language.  GCC will compile many different languages (C, C++, Objective-C, Java, Fortran, Pascal, and Ada to name a few).  Still not knowing what language you are using, you could try using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).  If your source is Java then you shouldn't have any problem compiling in Windows.  So much depends on these details.

Comment: OK! my computer language is C language, I am not really familiar with my source code. I got so many home work to do to study the code. My source code was not java.Thk you!

Answer (score 0):

You can run some windows applications in Linux using the compatible emulator using WINE.
http://www.winehq.org/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)

Which you can install from synaptic

Comment: OP wants to run Linux software in Windows, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a full install of the [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) package on your windows machine, you might be able to compile it on windows as well, in the same way that you do in the Linux environment.

If you transfer a linux ELF binary executable to a windows environment it will not work for very many reasons. The executable file formats are different, and the system calls / APIs are completely different.